# Twitter button replacing every link on the page in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: twitter

Twitter button is replacing every link on the page in Internet Explorer 8

I just copied and pasted the code from Twitter.

It only does it in IE8, however, in other browsers it shows the button count as #undefined, although it works.

It must be a conflict with other javascript files. I just wanted to see if someone else has had this problem before.

Thanks

Comment: I think folks may need a little more info to help with this.  Is it possible that it's applying a css style/class to every "button" element on the page via javascript or some similar mechanism?  Can you post a stripped down version?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it's a Twitter Issue you can follow the updates here: https://dev.twitter.com/issues/486

Comment: Twitter Support closed the ticket today, it should be fixed. (Tue, 2012-08-28 07:25 - Status Closed)